# Can not insert user into database in JSON Java Restful

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm facing the problem about insert user in database. Im using **Restful** and **JDBC** to parse data to android, I have two classes to perform insert user following as:

Register.java

```
@Path("/register")
public class Register {
@GET 
@Path("/doregister")  
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
public String doLogin(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("username") String uname, @QueryParam("password") String pwd){
    String response = "";
    int retCode = registerUser(name, uname, pwd);
    if(retCode == 0){
        response = Utitlity.constructJSON("register",true);
    }else if(retCode == 1){
        response = Utitlity.constructJSON("register",false, "You are already registered");
    }else if(retCode == 2){
        response = Utitlity.constructJSON("register",false, "Special Characters are not allowed in Username and Password");
    }else if(retCode == 3){
        response = Utitlity.constructJSON("register",false, "Error occured");
    }
    return response;

}

private int registerUser(String name, String uname, String pwd){
    System.out.println("Inside check registerUser method() ");
    int result = 3;
    if(Utitlity.isNotNull(uname) && Utitlity.isNotNull(pwd)){
        try {
            if(DBConnection.insertUser(name, uname, pwd)){
                System.out.println("RegisterUSer if");
                result = 0;
            }
        } catch(SQLException sqle){
            System.out.println("RegisterUSer catch sqle");
            //When Primary key violation occurs that means user is already registered
            if(sqle.getErrorCode() == 1062){
                result = 1;
            } 
            else if(sqle.getErrorCode() == 1064){
                System.out.println(sqle.getErrorCode());
                result = 2;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Inside checkCredentials catch e ");
            result = 3;
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Inside checkCredentials else");
        result = 3;
    }

    return result;
  } 
}
```

DBConnect.java

```
public static boolean insertUser(String name, String uname, String pwd) throws SQLException, Exception {
    boolean insertStatus = false;
    Connection dbConn = null;
    try {
        try {
            dbConn = DBConnection.createConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT into ACCOUNT(name, username, password) values('"+name+ "',"+"'"
                + uname + "','" + pwd + "')";
        //System.out.println(query);
        int records = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        //System.out.println(records);
        //When record is successfully inserted
        if (records > 0) {
            insertStatus = true;
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        //sqle.printStackTrace();
        throw sqle;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        if (dbConn != null) {
            dbConn.close();
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (dbConn != null) {
            dbConn.close();
        }
    }
    return insertStatus;
}
```

My table ACCOUNT:
[image]

When I debugged on **Eclipse**, I see the result return is fine, but If I use **Advanced rest client** tool to get data, it happened an exception:

URL Json:

```
http://localhost:9999/webserver/register/doregister?name=tester&username=tester@gmail.com&password=test12345
```

status of result response:

```
{
   "tag": "register",
   "status": false,
   "error_msg": "Error occured"
}
```

I have found and tried a lot of ways but not found the cause

How to fix the problem and insert user into database? Thank so much !

Comment: There is "Error occured" message in the response, which comes when return code 3 is received from registerUser(); however it is returned from both catch(Exception e) and the else branch. Which of these is actually happening?

Comment: Hi, in Register.java, exception happend at line: sqle.getErrorCode() == 1062

Comment: I have comment: "When Primary key violation occurs that means user is already registered", however new user is not exist

Comment: How does the ACCOUNT table look like, does it have any other columns than (name, username, password)? What column(s) are the primary key?

Comment: Hi @Hammerfest: I have more column in Acc table, I have posted photo

Comment: SQL code 1062 means that you want to insert an entry with an already existing primary key to the table. In your case the primary key is the ID column, and no value is explicitly given for that column in your INSERT statement. I can't try it now but it could happen that this way it always tries to insert the entry with the same primary key (e.g. 0). But it is still not clear for me, that if this is the error symptom, then this should mean result = 1 returned from registerUser() and "You are already registered" filled by doLogin() into the response and not "Error occured" as in your example

Comment: Yes, I suspect at ID column similar to you, it seem not allow insert new id and then it happen exception 1062, But I didn't understood why in back-end I still can create new user normal, and login is normal, just create new user is not allow :(

Comment: Perhaps you can try to debug the two scenarios in parallel and check if there is any difference. Is the String query the very same when you test it with the same input values from the backend only vs a real request; if yes, how it is progressing within stmt.executeUpdate(query) etc.

Comment: thank for your idea, maybe it will better for me if debug parallel backend and this service, i will back and inform you :)